# SqlCommand string to RowdataBound Header

Tags: c#, string, gridview, sqlcommand, executescalar

I have created a method with a string "**test**" that holds my SqlCommand query.
**test =  '201813'**

```
public void temp()
{
    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;    
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),120),4)+ CAST((DATEPART(ISOWK,GETDATE()) - 2) AS NVARCHAR(2))", con);
        con.Open();
        string test = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

The question now is How can I reuse this string in my following **rowdatabound event**?

```
protected void gwPlanning_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.Cells.Count > 0)
    {
        //Translate header text
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[12].Text = test.ToString();    
        }

    }       
}
```

I'm trying to use `e.Row.Cells[12].Text = **test.ToString();`

Can anyone help me on what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the string variable `test` is a local variable for the `temp()` and if you want to use that it in `gwPlanning_RowDataBound`, either you have to make the function `temp` to return a string value or you have to save the value in a global variable.

**temp() to return a string value.**

Code:

```
public string temp()
{
    string test = string.Empty;
    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),120),4)
                            + CAST((DATEPART(ISOWK,GETDATE()) - 2) AS NVARCHAR(2))", con);
        con.Open();
        test = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        con.Close();
    }
    return test;
}


protected void gwPlanning_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.Cells.Count > 0)
    {
        //Translate header text
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[12].Text = temp().ToString();    
        }
    }       
 }
```

Comment: This is perfect. You learn something new everyday :)
Thank you.